# What is the cartesian form of the complex number $\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\right)^{-7}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\right)^{-7}$$

The principle argument is $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and the modulus is $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.
I can't seem to simplify this to cartesian form.

[What is happening in the simplification after de moivre's formula?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuaN0.jpg)

Comment: Try $\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\right)^{-7}=\left(\frac{1}{2} (1-i)\right)^{-7}=2^7 \left( \frac{1}{1-i}\right)^7$. What is the cartesian form of $\frac{1}{1-i}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument and modulus are for the number before you raise it to the $-7$ power.  You need to raise the modulus to the $-7$ power and multiply the argument by $-7$ to get the polar form of the power.  Then if $z=re^{i \theta}$ the real part is $r \cos \theta$ and the imaginary part is $r \sin \theta$

Answer (score 3):

### Hint:

use
$$\frac{1}{2}(1-i)^2=-i$$

Comment: Right you are; and your hint shows that using DeMoivre is not the best way to do this problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\right)^{-7}=2^7\left(\frac{1}{1-i}\right)^7=2^7\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^7=(1+i)^7=\sum_{k=0}^7\binom{7}{k}i^k=$$
$$=\binom{7}{0}+\binom{7}{1}i+\binom{7}{2}(-1)+\binom{7}{3}(-i)+$$
$$+\binom{7}{4}+\binom{7}{5}i+\binom{7}{6}(-1)+\binom{7}{7}(-i)=$$
$$=1+7i-21+-35i+35+21i-7-i=8-8i$$